# How to start a Dockerized Django server with custom ip address?

Tags: django, docker

When we want to run a bare Django app we use the term: `python manage.py runserver <ip>:<port>` to start a web server with the desired IP address. I tried to do a similar thing with Docker and Django inside the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

volumes:
    init-db:
    data-db:

services:
    
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <name>
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <password>
        ports:
            - 27020:27020
        command:  mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null

    splash:
        image: scrapinghub/splash
        ports:
        - "8050:8050"
        restart: always

    web:
        build: .
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: >
          bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver <some_ip>:<some_port>"
        tty: true
        volumes:
          - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
          - mongo
```

Now after running it is giving me `web_1 | Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.`

Note: I get the IP address using windows' ipconfig then I select the ipv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the same code I added, restarting my pc was the solution that I did not expect.

Answer (score 3):

The process inside the Docker container must listen on the special "all interfaces" address 0.0.0.0.  The container itself has its own private IP space, and can't bind to arbitrary host interfaces.

Conversely, the `ports:` declaration in your `docker-compose.yml` can name a specific IP address to listen on, and this must be one of the host's interfaces.

So your `docker-compose.yml` file should look roughly like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ['192.168.1.2:8000:8000'] # <-- host IP address here
    depends_on: [mongo]
    # shouldn't need tty:, volumes:, or command:
  mongo: # as in the question, except
    ports: ['27020:27017'] # <-- second port needs to be standard MongoDB port
```

And the corresponding Dockerfile should look something like:

```sh
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
# #!/bin/sh
# python manage.py migrate
# exec "$@"

EXPOSE 8000
# Use 0.0.0 as the listen address vvvvvvv
CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```